# Array of JSON Objects to Knockout Observable Array With Observable Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, observable

My app has an ajax call that will return an array of JSON objects.

```
[
{"ID":2,"Name":"Name 1","CreatedOn":"/Date(1432892160000)/"},
{"ID":7,"Name":"Name 2","CreatedOn":"/Date(1432892160000)/"},
{"ID":8,"Name":"Name 3","CreatedOn":"/Date(1432892160000)/"},
{"ID":9,"Name":"Name 4","CreatedOn":"/Date(1432892160000)/"},
{"ID":10,"Name":"Name 5","CreatedOn":"/Date(1432854000000)/"}
]
```

I need to then assign these to a knockout observable array where the object properties are also observable.

I can create the observable array without a problem.

```
viewModel.newArray= ko.observableArray([]);
viewModel.newArray(result.ReturnedObjects);
```

However I can't suss out how to push to the observable array and make the properties of each object observable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Knockout Mapping Plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). Something like this should work

```
function vm(result){
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray();
  ko.mapping.fromJS(result.ReturnedObjects,{},self.items)
  console.log(self.items()); //array with each object props as observables
}
```